# How do I add fsp to DATETIME

Tags: mysql

[image]I am trying to add milliseconds to an existing table. The column `TradeUTC` is currently DATETIME.

```
ALTER TABLE `tempTrades` MODIFY `TradeUTC` DATETIME(3);
```

I get an error at the "("

Comment: Cannot recreate your case http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8bc97/1/0. Share more info and entire script.

Comment: I am running this query in TOAD - could that be an issue?

Comment: Share screenshot of your query and error

Comment: I added a picture to question

Comment: Why are you trying to create a datetime column with `(3)` this type is not a varchar, you can't specify its size.

Comment: @JorgeCampos The documentation says this is how to store fractional seconds i.e. 3 = millseconds

Comment: @ManInMoon Can you use console or phpmyadmin to connect to mysql and try again?

Comment: Could be my local version of MySql client that's the problem. But I cannot see how to find out which TOAD is using...

Comment: Which version of MySQL Server are you using - I think this format is supported from ver 5.6.4 onwards - earlier versions accept fractional parts in string literals but silently discard them

Comment: @ManInMoon Yup, **PaulF** is right with 5.5 I get the same error in Sqlfiddle

Comment: Heres the documentation : http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fractional-seconds.html meant to include that in the original comment

Comment: Actually, I am 5.6.24 on BOTH Server and Client... Could it be a TOAD thing - does anyone use TOAD?